# First iussue about GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm approaching to Google App Engine. 
I want to implement some handlers, but I get a "Oops! This link appears to be broken." error for each of them:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app


class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):


    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)


def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

if I used a simple print function (i.e. print "2gf"), all would work perfectly. 
This is my app.yaml file:

```
application: sample-app
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /aaa/aaa
  script: helloworld.py

- url: /bbb/bbb
  script: helloworld2.py
```

Suggestions?

Comment: why not use webapp2, python27?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is old, and the yaml file is pointing the python scripts/apps at the wrong urls. Try the code below:

```
import webapp2

class HomePageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write('Hello appengine!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                                   debug=True)
```

And the app.yaml file should contain something like this:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
script: helloworld.py
```

Also, go through the following [App Engine python tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld). It explains the main concepts of coding for App Engine really well. It helped me greatly when I got started.

Comment: If I use helloworld.app as you suggest I got an import error, because it does not exist. (it's helloworld.py).

Comment: Any of the following 3 should work helloworld.py, helloworld.app or helloworld.application

Comment: No, it doesn't work: 

    <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: Could not find module     helloworld.app 
      args = ('Could not find module helloworld.app',) 
      message = 'Could not find module helloworld.app'

Comment: Is the app.yaml file and your python files in the same folder? I can confirm it works on my end I use the .app prefix, either way it doesn't matter if .py works for you then stick with it. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.yaml` you do not have any routing instructions for `/`. Therefore when you hit a URL that does not match one of those already in your YAML, your app doesn't know what to do and shows you that error. In order to fix that you need to provide a 'default' handler for anything else that isn't specified in your `app.yaml`. As mentioned by @Tkingovr (+1 to him), you want to point the default (`/.*`) to your script. Add that handler at the bottom of your `app.yaml` and point it to your main script. However I agree with @Tkingovr - switching over to 2.7 now (when you're first learning) will make things easier in the long run :)

Comment: yes I know about this. I still get the same error, even if I insert what you suggest. Something's missing.

Comment: I worked the problem out. 
To implement multiple handlers I've to modify also WSGIApplication, passing as parameters the url which is mapped from that script. 
Bu no, if I use the .app extension, I got an import error.

Comment: @FrankBr Yeah, it sounds like you have a mixture of 2.5 and 2.7 going on. The `.app` extension is related to the 2.7 runtime, and it indicates that you are pointing your `app.yaml` handler to a particular app object (not script), so that it is trying to do is import the object located at the location you specify (not the script). The `app` in `hello.app`, for instance, indicates the `app` object (your WSGI which will contain your handlers, etc.) located in the `hello` module. In any case, glad you got it sorted out and good luck with everything!